# Not getting SQL query for UNION to return correct value

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, union

ISSUES with a UNION  query, where from one table, I need the COUNT of records for "Term" where I specify "ID" and "Count" fields.

**NOTE**  The grader is grading down if it suspects UNION ALL was used.

I'm trying a few different formats...and none are working correctly.

------(VERSION 1)-------

e.g.

```
    select count(term) from frequency where (select docid =
    '10398_txt_earn' where count = '1' UNION select docid =
    '925_txt_trade' where count = '1');
```

Gives me "0."   The grader tells me "0" is incorrect.

If I split into the two parts, I get a value for each (110 and 225).

------(VERSION 2)-------

I modified the query, using the format here:

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/UNION-QUERY-td42629.html

so that I now have for the query (BTW...unlike what the poster suggests, I have to use UNION...unless I can use UNION ALL then select unique records...but this seems like an unnecessary computational step)

```
   select count(term) from (select * from frequency where
   (docid='10398_txt_earn' and count='1'))
   UNION
   select term from (select * from frequency where 
   (docid='925_txt_trade' and count='1'));
```

gives me two lines of output:  line 1: 110, line 2:  225

If I replace 'select count(term)' to just 'select term'...I get a list whose length is the sum of the two values above

------(VERSION 3)-------

```
  select (term) from frequency where (select docid = '10398_txt_earn' 
  where count = '1')
  UNION
  select (term) from frequency where (select docid = '925_txt_trade' 
  where count = '1');
```

again, gives me two lines of output:  line 1: 110, line 2:  225

QUESTION???
How would you modify it so that you would get one value with count of the UNIQUE shared terms?

Comment: count is a reserved word.. I'm surprised you can use it in the where clause without escaping it in `[]`.  Additionally, do all the "TERMS" have a non null value?  If not your counts vary because count will not count null fields.  If you use a `count(*)` however, it will count all rows regardless null values.  Lastly, you're second query seems like it should return what you're after assuming count is a text field, docID are text fields, and term is never null.

Comment: 'count' has two roles.  the first instance, as in "count(term)" is part of a query...the second instance, as in "count = '1'" is because one of the fields in the database is called "count"

Comment: Wrap the `[count] = '1'` in brackets RDBMS may be getting confused on count function vs count field.  2nd does tablename.term have null values?  if so counting nulls doesn't work.

Comment: @xQbert `COUNT` is no element of the [list of keywords in Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Comment: no...i dont think count is causing the issue...it didnt cause an issue with the previous problems.  the union statement is wrong.  I need to know how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this

```
select count(term) from frequency where docid in ('10398_txt_earn' '925_txt_trade') AND count = '1';
```

However if you need to use a UNION

```
select sum(termCount) from (
select count(term) termCount from (select * from frequency where
docid='10398_txt_earn' and count='1' group by term)
 UNION
select count(term) from (select * from frequency where 
docid='925_txt_trade' and count='1' group by term)
);
```

Comment: I guess with the UNION it is supposed to omit duplicates in the "term" field...b/c this is the sum of both parts...and the grader is telling me to use "union" not "union all"

Comment: True, distinct will do that too.  count(distinct term)

Comment: I added "distinct" to make 'select sum (distinct termCount)' but I still get the wrong answer.

Comment: The distinct would have to be in the inner selects  by the time it gets to the select sum() everything is already counted.

Comment: The number I get back is the same.

Comment: Made a small change to the answers adding in a Group by, I know this is close.  might want to update with the actual code you are using now.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a count of both items (a where clause) and need it to also be where "count" ='1'? This sounds straight forward to me - a single where clause.

```
SELECT SUM(TermCounts)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT terms) AS TermCounts
    FROM frequency
    WHERE docid = '10398_txt_earn'
        AND "count" = '1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT terms) AS TermCounts
    FROM frequency
    WHERE docid = '925_txt_trade'
) CountUnion;
```

Comment: the assignment is to translate this into a query:  πterm(σdocid=10398_txt_earn and count=1(frequency)) U πterm(σdocid=925_txt_trade and count=1(frequency))

Comment: Yet you want 1 row out of that?

Comment: I want the count of unique terms that satisfy all requirements.

Comment: SQL's based in set calculations, but what comes out of it is often based on what specifically is required of the results. The set notation you used indicates perhaps two rows, each of which contains a count of the distinct terms. The query above would be more indicative of πterm((σdocid=10398_txt_earn or σdocid=925_txt_trade) and count=1(frequency)). The edit I just made counts distinct terms, so duplicates will not count more than once. Translations like this are difficult. Are you looking for one number, or an ordered set based on criteria?

Comment: Funny you say that...the only thing that has generated the answer that the grader is looking for (a single number) is:  
Select count(distinct term)
from frequency
where docid in ("925_txt_trade", "10398_txt_earn")
and count = '1';

HOWEVER, this does not use union...which the entire problem is about using UNION in your SQL query.

Comment: So, edited again. This is not how I would recommend structuring the query in real life. This is, however, a single sum of counts using the union all operator. Also, done this way so that the rows counting each term are not consolidated if the counts are the same, so if each count was 4, you'd get 4 as the result instead of 8 without union all.

Comment: Can't use "UNION ALL".  the grader marks down if it suspects it was used.  It's obvious that the application of the problem is convoluted and not how anyone would actually do this query.

Comment: Feel free to use union instead of union all, but the result will not be an actual count if the two counts are exactly the same, no matter what the grader thinks.

Comment: After I fix the part about 925_txt_trade also having count = '1'....It gives the same number as every other suggestion that I've gotten gives...save the statement that does not use union.

Answer (score 0):

got it...this works:

```
from (
select term
from frequency
where docid in ("10398_txt_earn") AND count = '1'
UNION
select term
from frequency
where docid in ("925_txt_trade") AND count = '1');
```